How can I make my website have the option to install the application in Google settings on my cell phone?
I made a website in html, css, js and published it, I noticed that on a website like mine the option to install application appears when I click on those 3 dots in Chrome on my cell phone, but on my website this option does not appear. How do I activate this?
I believe there is some code for this to be enabled, as this application appears to be just a shortcut to the website on your cell phone

Sounds like what you are looking for is a progressive web app (PWA): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps
